# How does java.util.concurrent classes reuse threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm talking about the `Thread` instances, if they get their `Runnable` provided as a constructor argument and you can only execute their `start` method once, how come the `Executor*` family of classes reuse them?

PS: I know and use the Executors classes which are nicer abstraction than bare threads, I'm asking this just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runnables (lets call them R) passed to executor threads are in fact wrapped inside other runnables (let's call them W). The pseudo-code of the run() method of W is

```
while (threadMustRun) {
    wait for new R to be submitted and assigned to this thread
    execute R.run()
}
```

It's actually more complex than that, but you should get the idea. To really understand what it does, look at the code the the `ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker` inner class.